# How to report Mod if a user is using more than one account to upvote his/her own questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, moderator-abilities, reporting

Is there any place where we could report this so that the moderator takes appropriate action against the user who is using multiple accounts to upvote his/her own answers?

Comment: Custom flag; explain in detail. That's the gist of it.